# can i set a base url for expect()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, restangular

My restangular call has a baseUrl set in a config file to `http://localhost:3000/`. So a call like

```
Restangular.all("awards").customPOST(award)
```

Calls at `baseUrl+"awards"`

Now when I write a test for this, i have to write:

```
httpBackend.expectPOST("http://localhost:3000/awards")
```

But later if this `baseUrl changes`, I will have to change it in a lot many `.expect()` methods.

Is there anyway to set a `baseUrl` for the expect method, in a config file somewhere?

So that the expect method something like-

```
httpBackend.expectPOST(baseUrl + "awards");
```

So that any change in the baseUrl does not require any change in the `expect()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an `angular.constant` and then inject that constant wherever it is required.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.constant('Configuration', {
  BASE_URL: 'http://localhost:3000/'
});

app.factory('RestApiService', function($http, Configuration) {
  var awardApi = Configuration.BASE_URL + '/awards';

  return {
    getAwards: fucntion() {
      return $http.get(awardApi);
    };
  };
});
```

Comment: You are welcome. It would be cool if you up vote the answer ;)